# QtCreator + SDL same projects different targets(Debian and Raspberry)

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, cross-platform, sdl, qt-creator

I'm developing an application that uses SDL Libraries using QtCreator as IDE.
My end target is Raspberry Pi but I've already configured a cross compiler to work on Debian.

My aim is to have the same project and just switch target on QtCreator, I've already configured kits for both platforms and even added the Raspberry Pi as device on QtCreator.

The point is that I don't know what to write into the .pro file to include different libs/includes and defines based in the target, here's a small piece of the .pro file:

```
whathere? # RaspBerry
        {
        LIBS += -L/raspberry/SDL_pi/lib/ -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image
        INCLUDEPATH = /raspberry/SDL_pi/include
        DEFINES += RASPI
        }
whathere?
        {
        LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/ -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image
        INCLUDEPATH = /usr/local/include
        DEFINES += LINUX
        }
```